# Leaflet, map non geographical resolution

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I've a problem with a non geographical map on leaflet.
I've set the map with example of leaflet site:

```
var bounds = [[10,10], [window.screen.availHeight,window.screen.availWidth]];

var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    maxBounds: bounds
});

var image = L.imageOverlay('urlImage.png', bounds).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

the resolution of my image si too big (14804px X 7686px).
When I go to set a marker on this map and change the ppi of my pc the marker are set to another position and this is my problem. How can I set a map that not change position of marker when I change the ppi of pc?

Comment: Set static bounds (not dependant on the screen resolution) and use `fitToBounds`.

Comment: but I need to render the map not on one resolution but at all resolution @IvanSanchez

Comment: Then change the map's zoom level.

Comment: @IvanSanchez but if i change the zoom level when change the resolution of my pc I have the same problem

Comment: No you won't. The marker will stay put.